Can I give access to my Xbox while prohibiting purchases?
I have some guests for long term and I would like them to be able to play the games I physically own as well as the ones I own digitally as well as my subscription. I don't mind giving them access to my account but I don't want them to be able to buy anything.
I've never really played it much so I'm not clear on what it can do.
Is this possible?

Yes, you can. See this Xbox Support article:

Require a PIN for purchases
To control any purchases that are made on your account, you can require a PIN before a purchase can be completed. This is especially helpful to Xbox family group organizers who want to approve the purchases that members want to make.

Note Be aware that if a member of your Xbox family group knows your Microsoft account password, they can reset your PIN and configure settings without your permission. Please do not share your account info with others.


Alternatively, you could probably just let them sign in with their own account as long as your Xbox is set to be your home console, according to this other Xbox Support acticle:

Making a console your home Xbox gives friends and family access to your games and content when you’re not signed in. Your home Xbox also lets you play your digital games offline.
[...]
Friends and family that sign in to your home Xbox have access too, even when you’re not signed in. For instance, a family member can play your games when you’re not using your console—they just need to sign in with their Xbox profile.

Your guests shouldn't be able to make purchases on your account or credit card, since they don't have access to your account. They'll probably still be able to make purchases on their own account using their own credit card, though. Note that since your console won't be their home console, you won't be able to access the games they purchase, even if the game has been downloaded to your console.

note that the second option is safer (for your account protection) and will allow the guest to play your games, but won't allow the guest to benefit from your subscriptions like xbox live. the guest won't have access to your game saves and unlocks, nor will streaming apps like netflix be signed into your accounts.

(as an example: my partner can play my copy of minecraft on their own account, but cannot play online unless using my account. the xbox we use is set as my home console.)

Frame Challenge: don't give them access to your digital games. You are responsible for any actions that happen on your account, and if they do something that gets you banned from Xbox Live or game servers, it's going to be a struggle to get unbanned. "It wasn't me, it was my friend" isn't a valid reason to get unbanned on most platforms.
Instead, as Nolanar said, let them log in using their own account.

That's more an issue of giving access to multi-player games than just digital copies of games, isn't it?
